# UINavigationController standard back button strange behavior (hiding without fading)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I do regular pushViewController, then tap back button (all controlls native). The first time I do it all is fine, but further times animation popping to previous controller is strange - back button dissapeares without fade animation. What can be wrong?

```
MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

browser.displayActionButton = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of MWPhotoBrowser. It creates new back button, the same as standard, but its behavior different.